# How to change the comment words font color in TeXworks (TeX Live 2023 version)?

Tags: texworks

We use TeXworks in the version that is shipped with TeX Live 2023. But the comment font color is grey, how to change its color?

Comment: The syntax highlighting is done by your editor, not by texlive.

Comment: Which front end editor do you employ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP posted an answer with the solution.

Comment: @MS-SPO you vote to close because there is a correct solution posted as an actual answer? That doesn't seem right. It might be closed because the question is unclear, but we can fix that - I just made an edit with an attempt of fixing the question.

Comment: @Marijn, thank you for your comment. There is a certain kind of questions, like this one, which have almost exactly one and only one answer. I.e. what other alternatives may be offered here as a solution? // It can be that "closed" is an improper flag in this case. Perhaps s.th. like "done" or "solved" is more appropriate.

Comment: @MS-SPO Please don't close questions just because they are "done". Depending on circumstances, closing them might even make them eligible to be automatically deleted by roomba. Instead the criterion should be: is the it useful for others? Voting to reopen ...

Comment: @MS-SPO Please also see this related discussion: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8789/36296

Answer (score 3):

We can change the configuration in the directory `texmf-config\texworks\configuration` and modify the file `syntax-patterns.txt` to set the syntax highlighting color for comments in texworks.

Comment: Welcome. If you weren't the OP, I'd ask why you think the OP is using texworks. I'm glad you found a solution and it's great you reported it for others, but please bear in mind next time you ask a question that only you could possibly answer this one. Comments on your question immediately asked which editor you used, because that's the crucial detail. This is not a 'texlive' answer; it is a 'texworks' answer.